# Max(x,y) and argmax(x,y)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation, education

I am writing my report and I got confused on this simple maths concept.

What I need is: I have 2 values i.e x and y and I want to use the maximum of either x or y as my length. So which statement is correct in maths terms.

1. Max(x,y)
2. argmax(x,y)

Comment: It is the first one, $\max(x,y)$. Where does the other one (argmax) come from? And, it is not a statement, but a term that represents a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\max(x,y)$ is the maximum of $x$ and $y$, whereas argmax$_{x,y} f(x,y)$ are the values of $x,y$ that maximize the function $f$.

Comment: Sorry but you say max of x and y.. I want max of x or y. is it same function.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but  $\max(3,1)=3$.

Comment: Yes that is what i need.. thanks